# cliick event not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

this is my function:

```
function bind_click_user_pages()
{
     $(".card-pages-own").click(function () {
       debugger;
     })
}
```

the site isnt entering break mode, thing that it should be doing 
and this is my function call

```
 api.post(`/api/blog/get_user_pages`).then(response => {
    response.response.forEach(response => {
        $(".card").append(`  
           <div class="card" id="page_card_${response.id}" datacol1="${response.id}">
           </div> 
        `);        
      });
  });
bind_click_user_pages();
```

and i dont know whats wrong

Comment: `response.response.forEach` the double response is on purpose?

Comment: yes it is
the route method is a post so its needed

Comment: all its workig expect the click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, it looks like your missing something in your binding selector: $(".card card-pages")
"card-pages" is probably a class or an ID, not an element.

Secondly, the binding function is outside the asynchronous api.post , so your div is probably created after the binding, it will not have the click event attached. To prevent that, you can attach the event to the document like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".card .card-pages", function() {
  debugger;
});
```

Comment: i have edited the question so, the classes names' aren't updated
but 
i have tried what you sent and it worked 
thanks bro